# Old 3d cartoon show about playing soccer in space to save earth from planet conquerors?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, space

I remember it was like a 3d looking animation, these kids liked playing soccer but they were bullied it was like a team of 4 or 3 maybe. The main guy, the leader, had blond hair and liked the girl with blue hair I think...If I remember right her name was Cloe? They were selected to fight for the Earth by playing soccer on an intergalactic soccer cup against teams from other planets. The game was held by a strong alien group who were planet conquerors and whoever won at the end their planet would be spared from destruction.

I remember the whole plot but when I google it all I get is galactik football, but is not that show. When they played, it was like superpower soccer and sometimes there was like no gravity for the ball, also they had 3 tries, once the ball went in 3 times it was game over. The arcs where the soccer ball went looked like lions or something made out of stone.

Comment: This is a good description but remember the more you add the easier it will be for someone to find this for you. If you have anything else to add, for example, when you saw this, please [edit] your question to include that info.

Comment: Cosmoball? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve8L4Naafa4&vl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *[Sendokai Champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendokai_Champions)* (2013-2014).

> Zak, Cloe, Kiet and Fenzy are four unpopular kids from Earth who are not very good at sports. One day they find bracelets that have the power to transport them to another dimension. There they meet Tänpo, the master, who explains that the Zorn Empire is about to conquer the Multiverse. The Earth is in danger and, if they want to save it, there is only one way: they will have to overcome their weaknesses, learn the art of Sendokai to become warriors, and win the Great Sendokai Tournament of the Multiverse.

Four kids are transported to another dimension and drafted by a small, elderly alien, named Tänpo, to take part in a football-like tournament called Sendokai, which they need to win in order to prevent the Zorn Empire from conquering the Earth.

The main character, Zak, has spiky blond hair, while Cloe has blue hair, and all four kids  wear wristbands that allow them to transport back & forth between Earth and the other dimension/s, although Tänpo informs them that they must keep the tournament a secret from everyone on Earth.

The goals in Sendokai resemble stone lionheads with wide open mouths. The mouths are blocked by force fields which must be struck three times by the 'do' (ball) in order to remove them. Only then can a goal be scored, and the first goal scored wins the game.

The first several episodes focus on the kids being trained by Tänpo, since they're terrible at the game to begin with, despite gaining powers as a result of the different environmental conditions in the other dimension/s.